# trouble solving the recurrence 4T(n/2) + n

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, recurrence-relation, recursion

I am having trouble figuring out how to solve this recurrence problem...

$$
\begin{aligned}
&4T(n/2) + n \\
= &4(4T(n/4) + n/4) + n \\ 
= &16T(n/4) + 2n \\
= &4^kT(n/2^k) + kn
\end{aligned}
$$

I lose the trail here and I cannot figure out how to finish it and actually find the complexity. Can anyone help? How can this be done?

Comment: Use the master theorem. Alternatively, you're almost there. What is the value of $k$ for which $n/2^k = 1$? Take it from there.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus thanks for your answer. That would be, $\log(n)$ if I am not mistaken. I thought that might be the next step from reading about the Master theorem ... but I know the final runtime of the recurrence is $O(n^2)$ and it seems like the solution you lead me to says it is $O(n \log n)$. Did I miss something?

Comment: A recurrence doesn't have a runtime. Also, if $f(n) = O(n^2)$, this doesn't preclude the possibility that $f(n) = O(n\log n)$. Recall that big O is just an upper bound. It doesn't have to be tight.

Comment: Furthermore, you seem to be missing the base case. Suppose that $T(1) = 1$. What does $4^k T(n/2^k)$ equal to when $k = \log_2 n$?

Comment: would it be $4^{\log_2 n}$?

Comment: You can simplify that expression...

Comment: is it $n$? I am unsure about how to simplify that

Comment: This is high-school math. Try harder. Perhaps try some examples.

Comment: ok so I guess it would simplify to $2 * \log_2 n$? But I still don't get what that is telling me...

Comment: So are you claiming that $4^x = 2x$?

Comment: Oh yes I made an error there $4^{log_2n} \rightarrow 2^{2\log_2n} \rightarrow 2^{\log_2n^2} \rightarrow n^2$, right?

Comment: Right, this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

We can use **[Master Theorem](https://ediscretestructures.blogspot.com/2022/03/master-theorem-for-recurrence-relation.html)** to solve this :

If a **Recurrence Relation** is of the Form

### $$T(n)=aT\bigg(\frac{n}{b}\bigg)+{n^k}({\log(n)})^p$$

Then, as per **[Master Theorem](https://ediscretestructures.blogspot.com/2022/03/master-theorem-for-recurrence-relation.html#:%7E:text=FOR%20DIVIDING%20FUNCTIONS%C2%A0)**, we have **Six Conditions** depending on value of $a,b,k$ and $p$

- If $\log_ba>k$
  Answer is $\theta(n^{\log_ba})$
- If $\log_ba=k$ and $p>-1$
  Answer is $\theta({n^k}({\log n})^{p+1})$
- If $\log_ba=k$ and $p=-1$
  Answer is $\theta({n^k}\log\log n)$
- If $\log_ba=k$ and $p<-1$
  Answer is $\theta(n^k)$
- If $\log_ba<k$ and $p\geqslant0$
  Answer is $\theta({n^k}({\log n})^p)$
- If $\log_ba<k$ and $p<0$
  Answer is $\theta({n^k})$

In any problem, our main motive is to find $a,b,k$ and $p$.

**In Given Problem**
$a=4$
$b=2$
$k=1$
$p=0$

Now, $\log_24 = 2$ which is greater than $k$ $(1)$
Therefore, Answer is $\theta(n^{\log_ba})$

**Putting Value(s)**

### $$\theta(n^2)$$